Azure Service Bus Topic - Using REST API to Send Message - Message going into Dead Letter Queue
I am using the Azure Service Bus API to send a message into a topic. This is the API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue
I am getting a 201 as expected, so the call is successful. But the message gets delivered into the Dead Letter Queue.Since I am calling via the API, I do not get a DeadLetterErrorDescription or anything like that back which I would normally get if I were using the SDK.
I researched and found that some folks have overcome this issue by passing a session id, which again would be possible only if I am using the SDK.
Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this issue?

The purpose of the dead-letter queue is to hold messages that can't be delivered to any receiver, or messages that couldn't be processed. messages can be routed to the DLQ for the following reasons.   Refer to Overview of Service Bus dead-letter queues

Thanks. I was just trying to figure out the reason why the messages were getting dead lettered. I have figured out why, I added a comment below with that info. I am trying to figure out how to overcome this issue.

I was able to find out the reason why the messages got dead lettered. The dead letter error description is "Session enabled entity doesn't allow a message whose session identifier is null". So because the topic is setup as session enabled, a session id is expected to be passed.
While using the REST API to send messages, a session id can be passed by setting a header property named "BrokerProperties". The documentation for that is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/message-headers-and-properties
By setting a header property like the one below, I was able to send a message and it reached the topic/subscription successfully without getting dead lettered.
"BrokerProperties" as key and "{“SessionId”: “{1234}”" as value

Using below code, we can send the message successfully and i have followed Microsoft_Document:
Used rest api https://{ri_name_space}.servicebus.windows.net/{ri_topic_name}/messages:
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
    namespace RithBus
    {
        class Program
        {
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                var ri_name_space = "ServiceBusName";
                var ri_topic_name = "TopicName";
                var ri_skn = "RootManageSharedAccessKey";
                var ri_primary_Key = "6YXOZPAvs3JrithhY=";
                var ri_url = $"https://{ri_name_space}.servicebus.windows.net/{ri_topic_name}/messages";
                TimeSpan expirySinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                var ri_exp = Convert.ToString((int)expirySinceEpoch.TotalSeconds);
                string rst = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ri_url) + "\n" + ri_exp;
                using var tst = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ri_primary_Key));
                var ri_sign = Convert.ToBase64String(tst.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rst)));
                var ri_SAS = String.Format("SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ri_url), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ri_sign), ri_exp, ri_skn);
                using var riclnt = new HttpClient();
                riclnt.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", ri_SAS);
                var ri_data = new { message = "Hello Rithwik Bojja!!!" };
                var ris = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ri_data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var ri_out = await riclnt.PostAsync(ri_url, ris);
                Console.WriteLine("Hlo, Rithwik Msg sent successfully");
            }
        }
    }

Output:



Thanks for your response. I am using a vended product so I don't have any custom code. But the product allows consuming any REST API, so I am passing all parameters as you did above.

I was able to find out the reason why the messages got dead lettered. The dead letter error description is "Session enabled entity doesn't allow a message whose session identifier is null". So because the topic is setup as session enabled, a session id is expected to be passed. But I don't see any way of passing it via the API call. I know if I do custom code, I could pass the session id as a property named JSMXGroupId. I am not sure how to go about this while using the API approach.
